# How to connect with gdbserver only when a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, gdbserver

With gdb I would write a .gdbinit file with the following contents:

```
break file1.c:32
catch syscall write
# more setup commands
run
```

This would make gdb run the program and stop at those breakpoints.

How can I do the same with gdbserver? Eg: Stop for accepting connections only when the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: Don't you have to connect to gdbserver to install the breakpoint in the first place?

Comment: It seems so. I'm looking for an alternative that lets me set the breakpoints non-interactively in gdbserver. Something close to a `.gdbserverinit`

Comment: That's not possible.  The gdbserver is pretty dumb.  It does not have access to the debug info, so it won't know the address of `file1.c:32`.  You need gdb-proper to read the debug info, and send the low-level commands to the server.

Comment: I wonder if there's an alternate implementation that's smart enough to do what I want